# Dygraph: mouse pointer goes out of sync

Tags: mousemove, dygraphs

When I try to rotate the dygraph by 90 degree, the mouse pointer gets out of sync and doesn't follow the highlighted point in the graph. I understand this is because now x - axis becomes vertical and y axis as horizontal but I don't know how to fix this issue. I tried pointing my own logic inside mousemove_ function of dygraph.js but couldn't make it work. Can someone please suggest me the code change I need to make.

Note: My app has both dynamic and static graph, so the mouse pointer should in sync with highlighted point for both static and dynamic graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came up in the dygraphs-users mailing list. See this thread: [Best way to draw the graph vertically](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/dygraphs-users/Best%2420way%2420to%2420draw%2420the%2420graph%2420vertically%7Csort%3arelevance/dygraphs-users/pXrjG8fSxKI/m4ZZ5ytjJuYJ), particularly Ransom Christofferson's message.